# Strange issue with Flow typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

In my React app, I'm trying to get everything to work properly with Flow's typechecking.  I've come across an interesting situation that I can't figure out.  Here's the pertinent code:

```
// @flow
export const UPDATE_SESSION_PROP: string = 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP';

// This fails
type UserEmailAction = {type: UPDATE_SESSION_PROP,
                        propName: 'currentUserEmail',
                        payload: string};

// But this works
type UserEmailAction = {type: 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP',
                        propName: 'currentUserEmail',
                        payload: string};
```

The error from flow is: `Cannot use string as a type because string is a value. To get the type of a value use 'typeof'.Flow(InferError)`

Aren't the two `type` statements above equivalent?

Comment: Hmmm, I think this may be the explanation: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4279

Seems like an oversight by the creators of Flow though.

Answer (score 0):

Like what the error states, you cannot use a value as a type. What you can do is something like this.

```
export type UPDATE_SESSION_PROP = 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP';

// This works
type UserEmailAction = {type: UPDATE_SESSION_PROP,
                        propName: 'currentUserEmail',
                        payload: string};
```

And the implementation of the second version actually has a different meaning. If means that you make `'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP'` as the only acceptable value for `type`

```
//This works becuase `UPDATE_SESSION_PROP` is considered Literal Type
type UserEmailAction = {type: 'UPDATE_SESSION_PROP',
                        propName: 'currentUserEmail',
                        payload: string};
```

[Literal Type - Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/literals/)

Comment: Yes, understood.  The problem with this approach is that I also want to use the same constant with the actual dispatch, such as:
```    dispatch({type: UPDATE_SESSION_PROP, 
    propName: 'currentUserEmail', 
    payload: 'rob@bob.com' });
```
Ultimately, type-checking is supposed to be helping us develop better code, not hinder us too much.  I could have a `UPDATE_SESSION_PROP` and a `UPDATE_SESSION_PROP_TYPE` but that seems like overkill.